# Resize image to many different sizes

Tags: images, fast-forward

What's the fastest way to resize an image in many differnent sizes at once?
Like, I have an image that's 1024x1024 and i want to resize it to all of these sizes:

LONG LIST OF SIZES

All sizes, different files.
What's the quickest way to do that?

Comment: Do you have an OS preference?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/) a try. It's command-line driven, so you could easily write a batch script to consume an input file which lists the filename and a list of sizes (properly formatted of course) and just invoke ImageMagick multiple times, once each per size.

There are also a bunch of different language APIs available, so you could even use the language of your choice.

Documentation for resizing: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize